# Group_Concat in Subquery to Remove Duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates, subquery

We have several duplicate Stores in our DB that need to be removed and we identify dupes by using the Store's latitude.

In this example of the Producer table, we would want to remove producerID 123 (our Production Table has 10K rows).

```
+------+--------+------+------+---------+--------+
| producerID  | producerName  | type    | lat    |
+------+--------+------+------+---------|--------|
|  123        | ToysRUs       |  Retail | 52.445 |     
|  124        | Toys R Us     |  Online | 52.445 |
|  234        | GameStop      |  Retail | 55.150 |
|  345        | Amazon        |  Online | 56.110 |
+------+--------+------+------+---------+--------|
```

*Store is the same as Producer

This query gives us all the producerIDs that have the same lat value.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'TotalStores', GROUP_CONCAT(producerID, SEPARATOR ',') AS 'DupeStores'
FROM Producer 
GROUP BY lat 
HAVING TotalStores > 1
ORDER BY TotalStores DESC

+------+--------+------+----+
| TotalStores | DupeStores  |
+------+--------+------+----+
|  3          | 123,124,125 |
|  3          | 555,556,557 |
|  2          | 666,665     |
|  2          | 777,787     |
+------+--------+------+----+
```

Then, we take those producerIDs (copy/paste) and run another query to remove those duplicates based on the type. Anything that has a duplicate AND has a type of 'Retail', we want to delete.

```
DELETE FROM Producer WHERE type = 'Retail'
AND storeID IN (123, 124, 125, 555, 556, 557, 666, 665, 777, 787)
```

How can we combine these into one query? When I try this, I get an error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
DELETE FROM Producer WHERE type = 'Retail'
AND producerID IN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'TotalStores', GROUP_CONCAT(producerID SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Producer 
GROUP BY lat 
HAVING TotalStores > 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join in the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE p1
FROM Producer p1 INNER JOIN Producer p2 
ON p2.lat = p1.lat 
WHERE p1.type = 'Retail' AND p2.type <> p1.type
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e178ff44b6fb2f21c17aa6adc320b740).